# Balloon class in c#.net for winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any balloon class in c#.net using winforms ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, but you can use [`ToolTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) and set the [`IsBalloon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.isballoon.aspx) property to `true`:

> `true` if a balloon window should be used; otherwise, `false` if a standard rectangular window should be used. The default is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip tp = new ToolTip();
        tp.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
        tp.InitialDelay = 0;
        tp.ReshowDelay = 500;

        tp.ShowAlways = true;

        //Gets or sets whether the tooltip should use a ballon window
        tp.IsBalloon = true;

        tp.SetToolTip(this.textBox1, "This is a Text");
        tp.SetToolTip(this.button1, "This is a button");
    }
```